# Low and High G snapshot

Tags: military, general-aviation, fighter

I'm reading Fighter Combat: Tactics and Maneuvering by Robert L. Shaw and ran into this passage which I'm having trouble understanding. I was thinking maybe someone with experience would understand better what it meant, specifically the "roll back in the opposite direction to get into the target's plane of turn". I'm thinking i might not be imagining the way the author intented me to do so since I can't understand what that means. Thanks in advance and sorry if I made a mistake with the posting of the question, is the first time I use this site[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you have to understand the issues with a high (more than 60deg) aspect angle gunshot. At these high aspect angles, if the target is at high speed, his Line of Sight (LOS) rate across your nose can easily exceed your maximum turn rate. This is what makes it a "snap" shot. You cannot "*Track*" the target. In addition, because of the high LOS rate, in order to "join up" to a position where the target will fly through the gun bore line within effective gun range (1000-2000 feet), it will require initially pulling so much lead that if your flight path vector is in the same 2D plane as the target is turning in, his aircraft will be blocked out by your radome, and you will lose sight.
[image]
Therefore, you have the two options described.

[image]

**Option 1**. You can initially pull more lead (almost to the collision course), and than turn with substantially less turn rate and G-load, while you close into gun range. If you are turning in plane, this would entail losing sight under the radome. You could do this and then continuously roll out of the turn momentarily to reacquire the tally, over and over, as you close. But generally, this is problematic, and the more recommended option is to perform the initial manuever by holding the target barely to the side of or on the edge of the radome, (out of plane), until you have closed sufficiently that the target LOS rate starts to increase - to where he begins drifting forwards towards the nose. Then, slide sideways slightly to bring the target back "in plane" so that his LOS motion will bring his aircraft through the gun bore line and the bullet stream. This option will generally result in a much higher LOS rate gunshot, and expose him to fewer bullets. But because it will be done with higher angle off (heading crossing angle), it allows for a safer overshoot and separation maneuver.

**Option 2**. Or, you can initially pull less lead, in plane, keeping the target just barely visible on the edge of the random, in order to maintain Tally-Ho, and then gradually increase the back pressure, turn rate and G-load, to keep the target on the edge of the radome, until the targets LOS rate, (and your turn rate to track it) has increased to just below your maximum. This generally occurs just outside the max effective gun range, (around 2500-3000 ft). Then pull harder to try to match the target's LOS rate just before you turn on the gun. You will *not* be able to *match* the targets LOS rate, but then, (if you are still in plane), he will fly through the gun bore line and the bullet stream. Using this option, you will arrive at this position (with the target flying through the bullet stream), with less angle off and Target LOS rate, and will potentially expose the targets to the bullet stream for a longer period of time, (more bullets), than using the other option.  This option (because you will have *less* angle off (Heading crossing angle), has the disadvantage of making the overshoot and separation maneuver more difficult, and, against a more maneuverable adversary, more dangerous.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation